# Galois group of the largest kummerian field over $K$

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, kummer-theory

Let $K$ be a field containing all $n$-th roots of unity with char$K$ and $n$ coprime. An abelian galois extension $L$ (not necessarily finite) of $K$ is Kummerian if Gal$(K/L)$ has exponent $n \in \mathbb{N}$. There is an inclusion preserving bijection between Kummerian extensions $L$ of $K$ and subgroups $\Delta$ of $K^{\times}$ containing $(K^{\times})^n$ given by
$$ L \longmapsto (L^{\times})^n \cap K^{\times} $$
$$ \Delta \longmapsto K(\Delta^{\frac{1}{n}}) $$
Thus, the largest Kummerian extension of $K$ is precisely $K((K^{\times})^{\frac{1}{n}})$. I want to determine its galois group.

I know that it is the limit of the galois groups of the intermediate galois extensions, and these galois groups are subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^r$ for some $r$, but I would like to determine the group more precisely.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For example when $K=\mathbb Q$ and $n=2$ we have the largest Kummerian extension is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\cdots)/\mathbb Q$, with Galois group $\prod_{\mathbb N}\mathbb Z/2$.

Comment: In general the Galois group should be the profinite completion of $K^\times/(K^\times)^n$.

Comment: $Gal(K(K^{\times 1/n}))=Hom(K^{\times 1/n}/K^\times,\mu_n)$